# Ansible and YAML special characters

Tags: syntax, yaml

I have a very complex command I need to run via the shell: command, but it has all kinds of special characters that I need to preserve. I also want to be able to add vars into the command line for multiple environments.

How should I format this so I don't get all kinds of wacky errors.

shell: OC_EDITOR="sed -i 's/node-selector:.*/node-selector: \"region=primary, zone=blah\"/'" oc edit namespace default

Later I will change zone to a variable {{ zone }}

Comment: Could I just use  shell:  | OC_EDITOR="sed -i 's/node-selector:.*/node-selector: \"region=primary, zone=blah\"/'" oc edit namespace default

Answer (score 0):

You could use a as task and registered variable with the environment variable. I havent tried this but it might work.

`- name: Echo OC_EDITOR
   shell: "echo $OC_EDITOR"
   environment:
        OC_EDITOR: "sed -i 's/node-selector:.*/node-selector: \"region=primary, zone=blah\"/'" oc edit namespace default
   register: sed_command`

`- name: Execute OC_EDITOR
  shell: sed_command`

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was with the single quote and NOT the backslashes. No other characters needed to be escaped. I also wrapped the entire command in single quotes.

Here is the final working command that worked through the --check function. I'm re-running to validate it works..

```
- name: EXECUTE - Change the node selectors for the default and openshift-infra projects
  shell: 'OC_EDITOR="sed -i ''s/node-selector:.*/node-selector: \region=infra, zone=blah\"/''" oc edit namespace default'
  ignore_errors: True
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

***UPDATED and removed extra backslashes.***